# What is equivalent of brain drain for skilled labour?

Tags: phrase-requests

What is the phrase when you say that there is movement of skilled labour from X country to Y country for better opportunities?

Is 'leaching of labour'valid usage? Please suggest some other phrase for business writing purposes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you understand *brain drain* itself to refer to?

Comment: By "for better opportunities," may you be asking about laborers, rather than labor, as it appears?

Comment: Brain drain is engineers, doctors, scientists or such getting premium education in let's say a third world nation but moving to a job and contributing in the work force of a developed/better opportunity nation.   Kai I mean labour(ers) but large numbers of such a workforce.

Comment: Okay, I asked since "labor" leaving would/could refer to the actual job opportunities,  so the clarification might be a helpful addition for responders.

Comment: Brain drain _is_ for skilled labour.

Comment: I am refering to technicians

Comment: brain drain is the phrase for technicians.  Leaching of labor -- no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Human Capital Flight** is an economics term for the migration of well-educated or skilled people. Though sometimes used interchangeably with *brain drain* it is somewhat more general.

**[Human Capital](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/human-capital)** is described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_capital):

> **Human capital** is the stock of knowledge, habits, social and
>   personality attributes, including creativity, embodied in the ability
>   to perform labor so as to produce economic value.
>
> Alternatively, **Human capital** is a collection of resources—all the
>   knowledge, talents, skills, abilities, experience, intelligence,
>   training, judgment, and wisdom possessed individually and collectively
>   by individuals in a population. These resources are the total capacity
>   of the people that represents a form of wealth which can be directed
>   to accomplish the goals of the nation or state or a portion thereof.

and Human capital flight quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_capital_flight) is:

> **Human capital flight**, sometimes called brain drain, refers to the
>   emigration of intelligent, well-educated individuals for better pay or
>   conditions, causing their places of origin to lose skilled people, or
>   "brains".